# dynamically adding controls in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls

I am adding controls dynamically in my webpage.
I add them in onload method.
everything is working fine..

But I m a bit confused about how it works..
I have read in so many articles that all controls get their values from viewstate before load event. Then how my dynamically added controls get their values when i am adding them in OnLoad event ie after LoadPostData event.

Answer (score 2):

Load them in Page_Init()

Review the page lifecycle for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

This is a helpful article as well:

http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0305101&page=2

Answer (score 0):

In a typical **GET** request, the controls are created at `Page_Init`. Since these dynamic controls are not part of page markup, so in **POST BACK**, you need to recreate. Be sure that when recreating, it must have same **ID** otherwise your events/values will not preserve.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added controls play catch up in the control lifecycle. Even if you add a control after it has missed the LoadViewState event, that event will still occur for the control at the time when the control is added to the page. I would suggest that any poor souls who have not had the privilege of reading this article, do so immediately:

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

**Source**:
Professional programmer, I do not claim to be an expert, but I have read tons of articles about ViewState. :)